# how to Create Nested router urs in rest_framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i have created a url using NestedSimpleRouter. And the url that i have created is that :

```
http://localhost:8000/api/category/1/subcategory/
```

And  In above url `1`  in the id of category .And my problem is that 
i want to create the url like this

```
http://localhost:8000/api/category/1/subcategory/1/interest
```

this `1` is subcategory_id

So How can i define Nested url for this url .My urls.py is given below:

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path,include
from rest_framework_nested import routers

from campaignapp import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('campaign',views.CampaignViewSet)
router.register('interestbundle',views.InterestBundleViewSet)
router.register('category',views.CategoryViewSet,'category')

category_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'category', lookup='category')
category_router.register(r'subcategory', views.SubcategoryViewSet, base_name='category-subcategory')




urlpatterns = [
    path('',include(router.urls)),
    path('',include(category_router.urls))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra actions to your viewset using [action](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) or [list_route or detail_route(older version of django rest framework)](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/release-notes/#35x-series) decorator. This decorator is applicable all ViewSets which inherit from `ViewSetMixin` class.